# How to run more than one UPDATE statements in AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I need to update 100 records all in one go and in one table of AS400 but when I am using delimiter `;` (semicolon) it is throwing error.

Seems it doesn't accept `;` in AS400 as we used to do in DB2.

Comment: Can you please post the code that is causing an error as well as the error message?

Comment: What interface are you using to execute the SQL statements?  IBM i Navigator?  RUNSQLSTM?  Something else?

Answer (score 2):

The STRSQL green screen interface for running SQL statements is intended for running only a single SQL statement at a time, and does not support running multiple SQL statements separated by a ;.

Interfaces / applications designed to run SQL scripts (multiple SQL statements), like IBM i Navigator or RUNSQLSTM, support the use of ; as an SQL statement delimiter.

Support for ; as a statement delimiter is interface / application dependent.

Answer (score 1):

If you have IBM i Navigator installed, then its Run SQL Statements window is probably what you want, and it may be registered as the default handler for .SQL files.  Create an empty new.sql file on your desktop and open it and paste your statements in, or save your SQL Statements in a .SQL file and open it.  Hopefully this will open Navigator's Run SQL Statements window for you.  Set your connection properties to system naming, and connect to your server. You Cass now run your statements individually or all together.